# awk - combine two filters into one

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have this variable in a bash script on ubuntu 12.04 which is set to show the available MB on the root partition:

`AV_MB=$(df -m |awk NR==2 |awk '{print $4}')`

Is there an elegant way to combine these two awk expressions into one? Or a shorter way with sed or grep or cut?

Comment: LIke: `df -m | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'`? `awk '$NF=="/" {print $4}'` is more robust...

Comment: Yeap, thanks. It's one of those questions where you spend an hour googling and are then embarrassed when faced with the simple, sweet solution. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: @Nahshonpaz `df` has the `--output` flag that can be very useful in such situations. e.g  `df -m / --output=avail |tail -n1`  or if you want to use awk  `df -m / --output=avail |awk 'getline'`  And if you want to use purely bash syntax:  `read -d '' -ra df_arr < <(LC_ALL=C df -mP /); echo "${df_arr[10]}"`

Comment: neat @val0x00ff , I'll check it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Awk works on the "pattern {action}" model, so you can combine those two processes into a single and correct:

```
 df -m | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

This, however, is fragile as the second record could change (on my systems, the root record is the third row), so you can match on the final field of the record for the root filesystem, like so:

```
df -m | awk '$NF == "/" {print $4}'
```

which ensures your pattern matches wherever `df` prints `/`.

Comment: That's a useful tip, with $NF. Cheers

Comment: Shouldn't `$NF` be equal to a number, what does it mean when it equals "/"?

Comment: @JoshRumbut `$NF` is a special awk variable that means the final field of a record.

Comment: I get it now, `NF` is the number of fields and `$NF` is the value of the NFth field.

Answer (score 6):

Since you know what partition you are looking for, just specify it in the `df` command:

```
df -m /
```

Also, you can use the `--output` option to define what columns you want to show. In this case, "available", whic

```
df -m --output=avail /
```

From `man df`:

> **--output[=FIELD_LIST]**
>
> use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields if
>   FIELD_LIST is omitted.
>
> ...
>
> FIELD_LIST is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  Valid
>   field names  are:  'source',  'fstype',  'itotal', 'iused', 'iavail',
>   'ipcent', 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'pcent' and 'target' (see info
>   page).

Note, however, that this `--output` option may be just available in GNU. Also, it prints the header, so you may want to pipe to `tail -1` to get the last line.

Comment: unfortunately on ancient ubuntu 12.04, df: unrecognized option '--output=avail' :-(